# Is there a dry-run option in Impala?

Tags: testing, impala, dry-run

Is there any way to test run a query and gain insight into possible query performance?

Comment: Like the `EXPLAIN` statement?

Comment: No, `EXPLAIN` can only be used with `SELECT` statements.